# Count number of items which hadn't been checked so far in the last x months

Tags: sql-server, count

We have a list of items. Each item may be checked/examined one or more times in the last @FromDate to @ToDate (12 months, for example). How do we count the number of items which were checked in a month that had never been check since @FromDate and display that count monthly.

The result would look like below:

```
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 1   May         2014    381
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000 2   June        2014    296
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000 3   July        2014    24
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 4   August      2014    260
2014-09-01 00:00:00.000 5   September   2014    249
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 6   October     2014    177
2014-11-01 00:00:00.000 7   November    2014    298
2014-12-01 00:00:00.000 8   December    2014    274
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 9   January     2015    41
2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 10  February    2015    0
2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 11  March       2015    0
2015-04-01 00:00:00.000 12  April       2015    0
```

So far we could count the number of items which were checked monthly by using the following query:

```
;WITH d AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2014-05-15'), 0)) as d, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as rn
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '2014-05-15', '2015-04-15') + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)    
SELECT 
    d.d,
    d.rn,
    DATENAME(MONTH, d.d) as [Month],
    YEAR(d.d) as [Year], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ItemNumber) AS Count
FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemCheck
    ON CheckedTime >= d.d
    AND CheckedTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d)
GROUP BY d.d, d.rn
ORDER BY d.d;
```

However, we still can't figure out how to count the number of items which were checked say in July 2014 but had never been checked in May and June 2014.

A simple single query below would be able to display that for a particular month but that doesn't display in monthly.

```
select count(distinct ItemNumber) from ItemCheck
where CheckTime >= '2014-07-01' AND CheckTime < '2014-08-01' and
ItemNumber NOt in (SELECT ItemNumber FROM ItemCheck as t1 where t1.CheckTime >= '2014-05-01' AND t1.CheckTime < '2014-07-01')
order by ItemNumber
```

**Update:** The ItemCheck table looks like below:

```
CheckID | ItemNumber | CheckTime
1         i1           2014-05-02
2         i4           2014-06-12
3         i5           2014-07-03
4         i1           2014-08-01
5         i1           2014-08-02
6         i2           2014-09-15
7         i3           2014-10-11
```

Comment: Please provide the DDL for the relevant tables.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with example schema for ItemCheck table.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table called `months` with one column called `month`.
Then you could do it something along these lines:

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = '2014-01-01'

SELECT months.month AS currentMonth, COUNT(ItemNumber) ItemNumber from ItemCheck
CROSS JOIN months 
WHERE CheckTime >= dateadd(m, months.month - 1, @date) AND CheckTime < dateadd(m, months.month, @date) and
ItemNumber NOT IN (SELECT ItemNumber FROM ItemCheck AS t1 WHERE t1.CheckTime >= DATEADD(m, months.month - 3, @date) AND t1.CheckTime < dateadd(m, months.month - 1, @date))
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY ItemNumber
```

You could also do it with a function, but you have to write it (function is called `dbo.Split` and you could write it this way: `select data from dbo.Split(',', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12')`. This way you could avoid creating another table (in-memory or a real one..)

If you want the code for `dbo.Split` I can provide it.

Comment: Hi @Jony, thanks for your reply. There seems to be some issues with this method. It doesn't always return records for x months (12 months for example). With the query we have in the question it always returns 12 records. Also the part where DATEADD(m, months.month - 3, @date) seems to only compare ItemNumber from 3 previous months.

Comment: What we'd like to see is for example in May 2014 there were 10 items checked. In June 2014 we'd like to count the number of checked items that not done in May. In July 2014, we'd like to count the number of checked items that neither done in May nor June 2014 and so on.

Comment: Well, this was meant as an example you can build upon, not a complete solution. Please try to play a bit with it and if you still need help I'll provide you with a complete solution.

Comment: So by the time you reach month 12th it should show the number of checked items that never been done in the first eleven months. (Sorry, just seen your comments. Will try to play with it and let you know.)